# Reading integers from multiple txt files and adding the values

Tags: java, file, loops, while-loop

I am just getting familiar with reading from txt files and in this one I have to read from about 3 txt files which contain 3 integers each and then add the values to a sum.(I placed a while loop where the 4th file is called zero and that's where the loop ends, just so I can get a simple grasp on how it works).

```
public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;

Scanner x = null;
String FileName;
System.out.println("\n Please enter file name: ");  
FileName = sc.next();


try{
    x = new Scanner(new File(FileName+".txt"));
```

I have to use a while loop so I thought that if I used the first while to loop through the file names, I can use the second one to read through the files while(x.hasNextInt()).

```
    while(!FileName.equals("zero")) {

        while(x.hasNextInt()) {

            int a=x.nextInt();
            int b=x.nextInt();
            int c=x.nextInt();
```

I used a sum variable for the sum of the ints (which are 3 in every text file).

```
            sum=sum+a+b+c;
            System.out.printf("Reading from "+ FileName+". The numbers are: "+a+" "+b+" "+c+" .The total is "+sum);
        }

        System.out.println("\n Please enter file name: ");  
        FileName = sc.next();
    }

}   

catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
{
   System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
}

sc.close();
x.close();
}
```

This is what I keep getting:

```
Please enter file name: 
n1
Reading from n1. The numbers are: 1 0 4 .The total is 5
 Please enter file name: 
n1
 Please enter file name: 
n2
 Please enter file name:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in a the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set `x` as a new Scanner once you finish the first iteration. Therefore, x.hasNextInt() could not be true because there are no integers left to read in the original file.

Change this:

```
try
{
    x = new Scanner(new File(FileName+".txt")); 

    while(!FileName.equals("zero"))
    {
        while(x.hasNextInt())
        {
            % code here
        }
    }

}
```

into

```
try{

    while(!FileName.equals("zero"))
    {
        x = new Scanner(new File(FileName+".txt")); % Scanner declaration shifted here  
        while(x.hasNextInt())
        {
            % code here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. The code works and I understand where I made the mistake.